# How to use instead of Select and ActiveWindow other code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little code what I want to reform a bit but I don't know that is it possible.

That's why I want some opinion about that can I do it in other way?

Here's the code:

```
Range("A17").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the same thing, without changing the selection:

```
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitRow = 17
    .FreezePanes = True
End With
```

Comment: Yes, that's it you and Raymond said that well. :)